# wiremock getting query param

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, wiremock

Is there a possibility to get query param from wireMock?

I need to check if the param can be decrypted properly, but all I could found is `withQueryParam()` which is good for matching, but since I don't know the result value of query param it's not really useful in this case, I need to get it first, then decrypt and then compare to previous value

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom request matcher and implement matching logic for any request property.

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/test"))
        .andMatching(new ValueMatcher<Request>() {
            @Override
            public MatchResult match(Request request) {
                return validateParam(request.queryParameter("param"));
            }

            private MatchResult validateParam(QueryParameter param) {
                // validate param
                return MatchResult.exactMatch();
            }
        })
        .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200))
);
```

For more options, check [Extending WireMock - Custom Request Matchers](https://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/)